# Is it possible in Django to have 2 different types of users with theirs own login fields in the same app?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-users

I have 2 types of users on my site, one is the store owner, I want to log him in with the usual custom user email and password, the other is the buyer, I want to login the buyer using just a pin number only. Is it possible to have both types of login users in the same django app. Thanks in advance.

```
class Store(models.Model):
store_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
store_status = models.BooleanField()
store_details = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank = True)
store_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
college = models.ForeignKey(Institute, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.store_name)+" "+ str(self.store_status)


class Customer(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
branch = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=BRANCHES)
sem = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=SEMESTERS)
reg_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
pin_no = models.IntegerField()
college = models.ForeignKey(Institute, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
```

Comment: pin number __only__? Surely you would have some other field also with the pin number?

Comment: actually I will be having login using fields either a pin or an rfid card (which is in effect another pin ) that's all I wish to have in the one login

Comment: Could you show your User model?

Comment: I've edited the question, thanks

Comment: Are Pin number and reg number the fields you want to use to autheticate? From what I understand you want to authenticate either from Username and password, or from pin now even if you want authentication via pin atleast one unique other field is necessary  (this information would be stored on user's device to give illusion that only pin is used) else it just takes one to randomly keep entering pins and get lucky. What are the fields you are using?

Comment: That gives a bit more clarity, so essentially I would need atleast one unique field eg, email other than the password even if I use custom user authentication rather than django's default authentication, is that how it is?      Actually it is a kiosk where buyers can books their items for the store. So I wantedt ogive the buyeers access in the kiosk by using an rfid card ( in another words only a password) but if the case is like what you told, I would also have to get them to enter their mail right, since kiosk can't store the mail in browser. Please let me know what you think about this.

Comment: Since RFID cards are made by you they can enforce uniqueness so that looks okay. I'll try to add an answer for you.

Comment: Note: do add a `unique=True` in your `pin_no` field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a custom authentication you need to add an Authentication Backend. Firstly your customer model is not related to your user model try adding a OnetoOne field in that. After that try adding code like this in one of your apps:-

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend

class MyBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, token=None):
        try:
            customer = Customer.objects.get(pin_no=token)
            user = customer.user
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return user
    
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Refer the documentation on [Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/) for more information.

Now after making an AuthenticationBackend you need to make it so that Django uses it, you do this by adding it to **AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS** in your `settings.py`, since you want the default username and password to remain something like this would work:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 'path.to.MyBackend']
```

Comment: I have gone through the documentation and now I see how your answer makes sense, I'll try it out and let you know soon, would it be better for security if the pin_no is hashed and checked. Would like to know what you think of that.

Comment: @SangeethJoseph I am not an experienced in Security so I cannot give any opinion on that, you would be better off consulting someone experienced in Security for that.

Comment: Works like a charm!! the code you have shown works for the auth backend, minor mistake is the part `def authenticate(self, request, token=None):`  it needs to be `def authenticate(self, request, pin_no=None):`   and  within the try : `customer = Customer.objects.get(pin_no=token)` be as `customer = Customer.objects.get(pin_no=pin_no)`.   That's all it works well, thanks for helping me @Abdul Aziz Barkat

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways for this. One is making an index place where they choose the option "owner" or "buyer" and after ask for login auth. Other approach is to make url specifying those options already. If you want to do it in the same "form" you could add specification under the hood for manage this input data provided also could be done by several ways, or make a checkbox like so it changes form input. Choose the one that suits you. Does this help you?

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I already have seperate login and home pages set for the buyer and owner. I have also provided the owner with username and password login page and the buyer with the single Pin login page. But my confusion is to whether it is possible to authenticate the login in both ways within the django app

Comment: you mean using djangos `auth.authenticate(request, user)` and if user is not none: `auth.login(request.POST['username'], request.POST['password'])`?

Comment: yes I mean that defualt django authentication or a custom authentication.